# SSIS Execute Process Task The process exit code was "1" while the expected was "0"

Tags: visual-studio-2015, ssis, sql-server-2014

I'm attempting to run an SSIS package as a job on a SQL Server.

I have an Execute Process Task in this package that uses a Putty application as the executable and the arguments are a series of commands to log in to an FTPS and grab files from it.

The package works on my local machine, but as soon as I try to run the job on the server, I am getting the error "The process exit code was 1 while the expected was 0".

Here is an example of the Execute Process Task:

[image]

Comment: Can you execute this command on the server on the RDP, for example?

Comment: @Ferdipux I can run the commands manually on the server on the RDP when I launch the exe, but not all in that one argument line as you see it there. It has to prompt for each thing i.e. username, password, cd, etc.
However, the single command does work on my local machine.

Comment: If I understand you right, you can run FTPS single command in shell on your local machine, and you cannot do this on server. In that case the problem pertains to the server, not to the SSIS.